# Carregar página e rolar automaticamente para um determinado elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Em uma página de contato há em respectiva ordem: um banner, mapa e formulário.

Como posso fazer com que, ao carregar a página seja rolado automaticamente para baixo deixando o inicio da mesma a partir do mapa?

Comment: scroll no eixo x ou y ? qual o tamanho da barra de scroll ? seria mais fácil você colocar o trecho de código onde tem o scroll e dizer onde é que gostaria que ele fosse posicionado

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No cabeçalho, `<head></head>`, adicione entre a tag `<script></script>` o seguinte código:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
window.location.href='#foo';
});
```

O método `ready()` indica que o script dentro da função será executado somente quando a página estiver pronta com todos os elementos carregados.

Dessa forma, não precisa colocar o script no pé da página, além de ser mais seguro.

No local onde deseja que a página pare de rolar, coloque:

```
<a href="#" id="foo"></a>
```

Comment: Resolveu totalmente o meu problema, muito obrigado @daniel-omine

Comment: Amigo, é possivel utilizar o código acima, só que com um efeito "suave"? Tipo ele vai deslizando até o elemento. Ao invés dele aparecer "de uma vez" na tela.

Comment: @PauloH.Hartmann, faça uma nova pergunta, específica para o que precisa.

Answer (score 1):

um exemplo seria `window.scrollTo(0, 10);` como não sei nada sobre o seu código fonte, o que dá p/ responder seria isso.

Answer (score 1):

Dá pra usar o próprio ID da página como referência pra usar como ancora
Exemplo:
Mas o # é necessário no javaScript
        window.location.href='#idDaPagina';

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma âncora:

coloque no final da sua pagina este código

```
<script>
window.location.href='#ancora';
</script>
```

e agora coloque um campo `<a href="#" id="ancora">` em baixo da usa div ou elemento html.