# Ao carregar (entrar) em uma página mover a barra de rolagem automaticamente até um elemento específico, sem clicar em nada

Tags: jquery

Já consegui fazer clicando em algum link etc, mas gostaria que ao entrar numa página a barra de rolagem vertical do navegador descesse até um elemento específico, sem precisar clicar em nada.

Comment: sem efeito de rolagem, pode fazer assim tb http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82850/carregar-p%c3%a1gina-e-rolar-automaticamente-para-um-determinado-elemento

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bem simples, aqui vai:

```
$(document).ready(function () { //Função para que o script comece quando a página carregar
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('DIV PARA QUAL A PÁGINA IRÁ').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Código tirado do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103534/scroll-to-specific-div-on-page-load

Comment: exato, funcionou perfeitamente. obrigado.

Comment: @user49454, quando uma resposta funcionar-lhe perfeitamente, você pode favoritá-la, assim saberão que seu problema está resolvido. :)

Comment: como se faz para favoritar uma resposta?